# Remove Site Collection Header from SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, spfx, spfx-extensions

We are building an SP community site on SP2019 On-Prem. How can we remove the site collection header with its buttons for anonymous access ?
[image]

I have read somewhere that this can be achieved by applying Restricted Read permission for anonymous users. However, this type of permission is not visible. Also, injecting a custom CSS will remove it at all but we need it to be visible for site admins.

Basically what we need to achieve is to not display any site administration functionality for anon users.